# Java JAXP or Xerces2 for XML process?

Tags: java, xml

I am using Java 6 and want to process (read and write) xml files (small files) within my Java application. Should I use Java JAXP or Apache Xerces2? According to this post, [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JAXP+vs+Xerces](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JAXP%20vs%20Xerces)

Java 6 use Xerces already. How about Xerces2? big different between Xerces (Java 6 JAXP) and Xerces2? Either should be fine to me and I just want to start with a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using JAXP since it's standard in the Java JDK. No need for external libraries